# position of jquery fixed dialog box , get broken once it resized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

i have dialog box that set fixed to position on the screen.
its all working great , but once i resize it ( and i need it to be resized ) 
the fixed position is break , and when i scroll the browser scroller it moves with it .
here is the code :

```
var layerNode= document.createElement('div');
    layerNode.setAttribute('id','dialog');
    layerNode.setAttribute('title','Basic dialog');
var pNode= document.createElement('p');

    console.log("msg var: "+massage); 
    pNode.innerHTML  = massage;

layerNode.appendChild(pNode);
document.body.appendChild(layerNode);

jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true, 
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 500,
    modal: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');
        $(event.target).parent().css('top', '5px');
        $(event.target).parent().css('left', '10px');
    }

});


jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  })(jq162);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position: fixed` use `position: absolute` and the dialog will no longer scroll *with* the page (most websites do this with dialogs in my experience).

Mostly unrelated, but you can rewrite this:

```
$(event.target).parent().css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '5px', 'left', '10px'});
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but changing it to absolute , doing what i want to avoid doing , its just scroll with the page